# i am using listview ,I have an error at the adapter class

Tags: android, android-fragments

this is my fragment page,am trying to create a listview

```
    public class MessagesFragment extends Fragment {
     ArrayList<String> brands= new ArrayList<String>();

    //String[] brands = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry","WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};
    public MessagesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);


        brands.add("microsoft");
        brands.add("ios" );
        brands.add("android");
        AdapterListView adapter = new AdapterListView(brands,getActivity());

        ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);
    }
}
```

this is my adapter class

```
    public class AdapterListView extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> brands;

    public AdapterListView(ArrayList<String> brands, Context context) {
        this.brands = brands;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return brands.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_listview,null);
        ListView lv=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
         lv.getAdapter();

        return view;
    }
}
```

I need to set the list brands ..currently am not getting any of the value in list brands. I think the error is at last section of adapter class

Comment: paste your activity_listview.xml here.. and where you are setting data in list view row??

Answer (score 5):

you should 
`return rootView;` in your `onCreateView` method of your `MessagesFragment`

instead of

```
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Rustam said in his answer you need to return the `rootView` from there.
i think there should be some more changes in `getview()` of your adapter class as..

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_listview,null);
 // layout.activity_listview should be your custom row layout with textview
 // find the TextView of your custom row and set data on it,,
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextview);
    tv.setText(brands.get(i));

    return view;
}
```

Comment: public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
 
        view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_listview,null);
        ListView lv=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
        lv.setText(brands.get(i));

        return view;
    }

Comment: when i given this thr is an error at setText (cannot resolve method settext-lang.string)

Comment: because you can't set text on list view you need to make another layout(contains textview) for your custom row that need to be added in your list view.. at your getview() method.. where you putted `R.layout.activity_listview`.. and you need to change the list view in adapter as i have specified in my answer,,